# how to pass extra parameter to as_json from controller to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

There are two apis in a controller. I need image for main_category and icon for nav-category. How can i pass xtra parameter from controller and can differentiate in model that this request is from main_category and this is from nav_category. Please help.

```
def main_category
    category = Category.all
    render :json => :include => {:success=> true,:data => category.as_json(@a,:only => [:name,:image_url])}

  end

  def nav_category
    category = Category.all
    render :json => {:success=> true,:data => category.as_json(:only => [:name,:icon_url])}
  end
```

as_json in model is as :

```
def as_json(options = { })
    if self.id == nil
    category = self.category
  elsif(@a=='main')
    h = super(options)
      h[:image_url]= "http://#{$request.try(:host_with_port)}#{self.image.url}"

      h
    else
      h = super(options)
      h[:image_url]= "http://#{$request.try(:host_with_port)}#{self.image.url}"
      h[:icon_url]= "http://#{$request.try(:host_with_port)}#{self.icon.url}"
      h
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is passing custom option to as_json method to differentiate them.

Controller:

```
def main_category
  categories = Category.all
  render :json => {
    :success=> true,
    :data => categories.as_json(:only => [:name,:image_url], :category => "main")
  }
end

def nav_category
  categories = Category.all
  render :json => {
    :success=> true,
    :data => categories.as_json(:only => [:name,:image_url], :category => "nav")
  }
end
```

Model :

```
def as_json(options = { })
  h = super(options)
  if (options[:category] == 'main') {
    h[:image_url]= "http://#{$request.try(:host_with_port)}#{self.image.url}"
  } elsif (options[:category] == 'nav') {
    h[:image_url]= "http://#{$request.try(:host_with_port)}#{self.image.url}"
    h[:icon_url]= "http://#{$request.try(:host_with_port)}#{self.icon.url}"
  }

  h
end
```